# Contraction of antisymmetric tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

Let $\omega^{ab}$ be antisymmetric in the indices $a$ and $b$. Why we have

$$\omega^{ab}(\theta_{ab}-\theta_{ba})=2\omega^{ab}\theta_{ab}$$

Comment: Hint: you can rename dummy indices

Answer (score 4):

$$\omega^{ab}(\theta_{ab}-\theta_{ba})=\omega^{ab}(\theta_{ab})-\omega^{ab}(\theta_{ba})=\omega^{ab}(\theta_{ab})+\omega^{ba}(\theta_{ba})=2\omega^{ab}(\theta_{ab})$$
where the last but one equality holds since $w$ is antisymmetric and the last equality is due only to rename the dummy indices (so the indices summed over)  as suggested in a comment; in particular you have to rename $a$ as $b$ and viceversa, in the second term given by $\omega^{ba}(\theta_{ba})$.